# Complex grouping in SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm querying a dataset of ~15 million records in SQL.

I've grouped and sorted the the data so looks like this.

```
TruckID RoadID  Date    Time    I want this
Truck1  200 22-Jan-15   9:33:01 AM  1
Truck1  200 22-Jan-15   9:34:18 AM  1
Truck1  200 22-Jan-15   11:10:56 AM 2
Truck1  200 22-Jan-15   11:11:30 AM 2
Truck12 150 22-Jan-15   5:41:45 PM  1
Truck12 150 22-Jan-15   5:41:55 PM  1
Truck12 150 22-Jan-15   11:03:01 PM 2
Truck12 150 22-Jan-15   11:03:41 PM 2
Truck12 150 22-Jan-15   11:45:37 PM 3
Truck16 330 22-Jan-15   2:18:22 AM  1
Truck16 330 22-Jan-15   2:35:25 AM  2
Truck16 330 22-Jan-15   2:35:50 AM  2
Truck2  500 22-Jan-15   10:00:12 AM 1
Truck2  500 22-Jan-15   10:00:22 AM 1
Truck2  500 22-Jan-15   10:35:55 AM 2
Truck7  10  22-Jan-15   7:15:08 AM  1
Truck7  10  22-Jan-15   7:15:45 AM  1
Truck7  10  22-Jan-15   11:10:56 AM 2
Truck8  20  22-Jan-15   1:15:07 PM  1
Truck8  20  22-Jan-15   1:16:07 PM  1
Truck8  20  22-Jan-15   1:55:10 PM  2
Truck8  20  22-Jan-15   1:55:10 PM  2
```

I want to know if there's a way in SQL to create the values in the `I want this` field. The logic is that if there's more than a two-minute (120 second) gap between timestamps in the `Time` field for the same TruckID on the same RoadID, a new value, incremented by 1, should be created in the `I want this` field for that TruckID-RoadID grouping. Thank you.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this data is actually sitting in a Spark RDD. I want to use Spark's sql context specifically.

Comment: It might be easier /more efficient to use `collect_list` and then `explode` -- do something like `groupBy($"TruckID", $"RoadID").agg(collect_list(struct($"Date" as "Date", $"Time" as "Time")) as "datetimes").explode($"datetimes"){ ... }` and then do your logic in the `...` part.

Comment: did you try to skip Spark SQL and use combineByKey on RDD?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Maybe you have tried a ROW_NUMBER, although that will not quite get what you want but it's close:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TruckID, RoadID ORDER By DateTime) as TruckRoadID
```

I think you need to create a [common table expresion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=common%20table%20expression) to join the table with itself to the next record based on truck and road, and then use a ROW_NUMBER() on that common table expresion.

Comment: Yeah, right now my team and I are using a lag function. It works fine in Spark if we cut down the dataset, but fails when we try to run it on the whole thing. We boosted memory. Job runs longer, but still fails. I'm thinking lagging is too memory intensive.

Comment: Can you post your lag logic? Would be a big help if you post the code you already tried.